# How to run macro by different UserIDs in a workbook with data connections

Tags: vba, excel, oledb

My workbook has several data connections from another excel workbook. I keep my sources in my Downloads file. My code refreshes data and filldown formulas. But I want this code to be able to be used by other users.

The idea is people who are going to use this macro, keep their source file in their own Downloads file, and changing input (UserID), code can reach related location. But code is not working. Here is my code (works with my UserID):

```
UserID = InputBox("Your UserID:")

For i = 1 To 4
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).OLEDBConnection
        .SourceDataFile = "C:\Users\" & UserID & "\Downloads\Source.xlsx"
        .SourceConnectionFile = "C:\Users\" & UserID & "\Downloads\Source.xlsx"
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
    End With
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    Range("Table" & i & "[[ColumnName1]:[ColumnName2]]").FillDown
    Range("Table" & i).Calculate
Next i
```

Here I have created very basics of what I am doing:

Lets suppose

```
My UserID: A1234 and Another UserID: Z4321
```

If I run code above `using Z4321`
code still accesses MY Downloads File and imports data which it SHOULDN'T be. I think it should give an error.How can it reach a file which does not exist in my computer?

Then I realize that if I use the code above it changes this path:

```
Excel> Data> Connections> Properties> Definition> Connection File
it writes C:\Users\Z4321\Downloads\Source.xlsx
```

[link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNNho.jpg)

But this path still remains with my UserID:

```
Excel>Data>New Query> Data Source Settings 
it still writes C:\Users\A1234\Downloads\Source.xlsx
```

[link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7lot.jpg)

How can I change pathway in link2 using VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set up variables depending on the username?

```
Sub test()
Dim userName As String, userFolder As String

' Get userName
userName = Application.userName  ' Or use the inputbox if you prefer.

Select Case userName
Case "BruceWayne"
    userFolder = "C:\Users\Bruce\myFiles\"
Case "Alfred"
    userFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Alfred\Files\"
Case Else
    userFolder = "C:\Users\Guest\Files\"
End Select

For i = 1 To 4
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).OLEDBConnection
        .SourceDataFile = userFolder & "Source.xlsx"
        .SourceConnectionFile = userFolder & "Source.xlsx"
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
    End With
    'etc etc
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually this is the situation in my workplace where every employee has an ID number like I suppose (A74892, E38523 etc) which you use to login. I think problem is not with variable set but with the for loop itself. Properties .SourceDataFile and .SourceConnectionFile are not working as I want or most probably I am using wrong Object. I should be able to change the pathway in link2 but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: if I state in an other way, code above changes connection name (link1) but interestingly doesn't change where it connects (link2)